# TensorFlow LinearRegressor doesn't converge on Simple Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have created a dummy regression dataset

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
X, y = make_regression(n_features=1, noise=15)
```

Which looks like:[image: Sample Regression Dataset]

And then created LinearRegressor using Estimator API

```
feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("X", shape=[1])]
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feat_cols)
input_function = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"X": X}, y, batch_size=4, 
                                                    shuffle=True, num_epochs=None)
estimator.train(input_fn=input_function, steps=1000)
```

But it, for some reason, doesn't converge

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into /tmp/tmpevbf55ce/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 32492.004, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 356.786
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 28372.191, step = 101 (0.286 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 410.94
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 17810.11, step = 201 (0.241 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 473.588
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 23634.676, step = 301 (0.213 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 475.631
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 22925.46, step = 401 (0.210 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 381.111
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 35689.633, step = 501 (0.269 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 341.871
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 12368.4375, step = 601 (0.296 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 374.349
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 23559.09, step = 701 (0.257 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 379.525
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 8804.063, step = 801 (0.262 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 390.375
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 15016.509, step = 901 (0.256 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1000 into /tmp/tmpevbf55ce/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 4406.3345.
```

I read other posts on SO that the dimensions of X and y need to match so I also went ahead and reshaped them:

```
input_function = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"X": X)}, y.reshape(-1, 1), 
                                                    batch_size=4, shuffle=True, 
                                                    num_epochs=None)
```

But it still doesn't converge. I am perhaps missing something, is it the batch_size? or the number of iterations? I've tried Linear Regression without using the Estimator API using TensorFlow's `GradientDescentOptimizer` and it converges successfully. I am not sure what exactly I am missing here.

Comment: How do you print this output?

Comment: @NipunWijerathne Do you mean the debug information?

Comment: Yes, When I run your code, it shows nothing

Comment: Use Jupyter Notebook. Executing `estimator.train()` will generate the log

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: Try running it for longer than 1000 steps, and increasing the batch size (to 32 or 64 or more).

Answer (score 0):

If you set `shuffle = false` in `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` as follows,

```
input_function = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"X": X}, Y, batch_size=4,
                                                    shuffle=False, num_epochs=None)
```

the output seems reasonable to me.

However, I think the reason is with your data it's hard to learn a linear model. When `shuffle=False` model try to overfit and `shuffle=True` model learns nothing.

**EDITED**

You can also try the **Gradientdescent** optimizer as follows.

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feat_cols,optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1))
```

Or you can continue to use the same **FtrlOptimizer**, which is the default optimizer of tf.estimator.LinearRegressor with increased learning rate.

```
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feat_cols,optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate=1))
```

I think both should converge when `shuffle = True`.

However, I'm not sure exact reason for not converging when `shuffle = True` with default settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think the Linear Model is hard to learn. As I said using `GradientDescentOptimizer` I couldn't get near full accuracy.

Comment: I mean I could**